# angular 6 (Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined)

Tags: angular, angular6

can't start new project.

**$ ng serve --open**
Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again.

see this error every time, did what write above, deleted and installed, updated and deleted anyway , help please what is wrong

```
**$ ng -v**
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.6.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.6.3
@angular-devkit/core            0.6.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      0.6.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             0.6.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.6.3 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.2.0
typescript                      2.7.2
```

**$ npm list --depth=0**

```
 +-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.3
+-- @angular/animations@6.0.3
+-- @angular/cli@6.0.3
+-- @angular/common@6.0.3
+-- @angular/compiler@6.0.3
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.3
+-- @angular/core@6.0.3
+-- @angular/forms@6.0.3
+-- @angular/http@6.0.3
+-- @angular/language-service@6.0.3
+-- @angular/platform-browser@6.0.3
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.0.3
+-- @angular/router@6.0.3
+-- @types/jasmine@2.8.7
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3
+-- @types/node@8.9.5
+-- codelyzer@4.2.1
+-- core-js@2.5.6
+-- jasmine-core@2.99.1
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- karma@1.7.1
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@1.4.3
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.2
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
+-- protractor@5.3.2
+-- rxjs@6.2.0
+-- ts-node@5.0.1
+-- tslint@5.9.1
+-- typescript@2.7.2
`-- zone.js@0.8.26

npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by minizlib@1.1.0
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by minizlib@1.1.0
```